# How to setup nginx to transmit static files only when they are modified

Tags: http, nginx, caching, browser-cache

I am using nginx to serve a folder. I am changing files in the folder by other process. I want to setup nginx in such a way that if file is not changed on server, file contents are not sent over http. When file is changed (i.e. modified date has been changed), file is transferred. I've looked through some docs and done some googling, but haven't found approach for this scenario. Most of the time people are purging cache folder, but this doesn't seem very elegant for me. Is it possible to organize this via 304/200 codes? I.e. if file is changed, server responds with HTTP 200 and its content, else with HTTP 304.

Comment: Found via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814201/nginx-does-not-refresh-file-after-repeated-changing-old-last-modified-header-is

Comment: can you please make sure to award the bounty at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814201/nginx-does-not-refresh-file-after-repeated-changing-old-last-modified-header-is?  If there's anything that's still a pressing issue, do let me know; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to configure:

This is already the default behaviour; for this to work properly, the client must be sending the `If-Modified-Since` and/or `If-None-Match` `ETag` headers, as per [ngx_http_not_modified_header_filter()](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.c#ngx_http_not_modified_header_filter) and http://nginx.org/r/if_modified_since.

---

## How to test:

You can easily test this with [curl](http://ports.su/net/curl) by looking up the `Last-Modified` field of a given resource, and then making a subsequent request of the same resource with the `exact` same date in a `If-Modified-Since` header (same for [`ETag` and `If-None-Match`](//serverfault.com/questions/950043/nginx-proxy-cache-and-if-none-match/950640#950640), respectively).

---

### Using `curl` to test `If-Modified-Since` / `Last-Modified`:

```
%curl -i bmap.su | & fgrep -e Date -e HTTP -e Length -e Modified
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 04:20:17 GMT
Content-Length: 12842
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:16 GMT

%curl -i -H"If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:16 GMT" bmap.su | & fgrep -e Date -e HTTP -e Length -e Modified
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 04:20:41 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:16 GMT

%curl -i -H"If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:17 GMT" bmap.su | & fgrep -e Date -e HTTP -e Length -e Modified
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 04:27:47 GMT
Content-Length: 12842
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:16 GMT
```

In the example above:

1. We first see what the `Last-Modified` date of a resource is.
2. We make a subsequent request with the `If-Modified-Since` request header that's *identical* to the date from the prior `Last-Modified` response header; note that we get a `304 Not Modified` response, which, as expected by the lack of a `Content-Length` field, does not come with any response body, saving the bandwidth.
3. We finally test the default settings of nginx for this feature; as per http://nginx.org/r/if_modified_since, it's an `exact` match by default; hence, if we provide a non-exact date (whether an earlier or a later one), then we're back to a `200 OK` and a full response body (this is usually what you want in order to avoid cache poisoning when the `Last-Modified` date gets reverted to an earlier one).

---

### Using `curl` to test `If-None-Match` / `ETag`:

```
%curl -i nginx.org | & fgrep -e HTTP/ -e Date: -e Server: -e Length: -e Modified: -e ETag:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.7
Date: Sat, 10 Aug 2019 05:24:06 GMT
Content-Length: 9053
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 12:20:32 GMT
ETag: "5d36fb90-235d"

%curl -i -H "If-None-Match: 5d36fb90-235d" nginx.org | & fgrep -e HTTP/ -e Length: -e Modified: -e ETag:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 9053
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 12:20:32 GMT
ETag: "5d36fb90-235d"

%curl -i -H 'If-None-Match: "5d36fb90-235d"' nginx.org | & fgrep -e HTTP/ -e Length: -e Modified: -e ETag:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jul 2019 12:20:32 GMT
ETag: "5d36fb90-235d"
```

Here's what we were doing above:

1. In the first step, we make a request to find the entity tag via the `ETag` response header; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag.
2. In the second step, we make a request with the `ETag` being provided in the `If-None-Match` request header; note that we forgot to put the quotes around it, which, apparently, is mandatory, for both nginx and Apache (as can easily be verified against httpd.apache.org host).
3. In the third step, we make a proper corrected request with the actual `If-None-Match` request header, receiving a `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` response w/o a body, as expected.

Comment: can you please supply configuration example?

Comment: @StepanYakovenko There's nothing to configure on the nginx side here, it should just work all by itself. Do you have any proof of it not working?  I did some explanation of the code at stake over at https://serverfault.com/questions/950043/nginx-proxy-cache-and-if-none-match/950640#950640, if you're interested in details, but, basically, you can easily test it with things like `curl -v -H"If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 17:18:16 GMT" bmap.su`, making sure to provide an EXACT date from the `Date` header of a response for a given URL (`exact` is the default setting).

Comment: @StepanYakovenko I've updated the answer to show how you can test that it's all working

Comment: @StepanYakovenko, if this solves the question, I'd appreciate an upvote and accept; if not, please advise if you're still looking for any specific configuration options. Thanks!